# rails path helper doesnt work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Hello im learning Rails on my testing app and i have this code

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= category.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', backend_category %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_backend_categories(category) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', backend_category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

and Rake routes shows me this

```
           home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                  home#index
                 root        /                                      home#index
              contact        /contact(.:format)                     home#contact
         backend_root        /backend(.:format)                     backend/admin#index
   backend_categories GET    /backend/categories(.:format)          backend/categories#index
                      POST   /backend/categories(.:format)          backend/categories#create
 new_backend_category GET    /backend/categories/new(.:format)      backend/categories#new
edit_backend_category GET    /backend/categories/:id/edit(.:format) backend/categories#edit
     backend_category GET    /backend/categories/:id(.:format)      backend/categories#show
                      PUT    /backend/categories/:id(.:format)      backend/categories#update
                      DELETE /backend/categories/:id(.:format)      backend/categories#destroy
```

but **im getting error that backend_category doesnt exist**

here is image
http://www.nahraj-obrazek.cz/?di=213711395092

whats wrong ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add `_path` to your `link_to` helper url, like so

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= category.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', backend_category_path(category) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_backend_category_path(category) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', backend_category_path(category), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you it helped, but now it saying 
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"backend/categories"}
what now ? :-) in Controller i have def show

Answer (score 1):

Following Luis answer, any `show` path needs a reference to an object. So I believe it should be

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', backend_category_path category %></td>
```

Which can also be written as:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
```

Comment: thank you, but im getting new error please look
new img http://www.nahraj-obrazek.cz/?di=813711414873

Comment: Update your question with all the errors you get. It will help all members to see what your problem is and help you out.

Comment: it works, thanks :-) [category parameter in path was missing]

Comment: Glad it works. If you have found anything other than the answers given, include it in your question so other members with similar issues can be helped.