# Rails - Create Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app where a user can create a product. On the product page I have an edit link and some text.

When I create a new product. I get

> Routing Error No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"products"}

However, when I check my database the product was created and I can view the page just fine. Including the edit button.

**product page (haml)**

```
   = @product.name
   %br
   = @product.description
   %br
   - if current_user.admin || @product.user_id == current_user.id
     = link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path
     = link_to 'Delete', @product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
```

**products controller**

```
  class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_login
  before_filter :current_user, only: [:create, :destory]
  before_filter :admin_and_author, only: [:destory, :edit]
  before_filter :admin_user, only: :index

  def new 
    @product = Product.new
    @photo = Photo.new
    4.times{ @product.photos.build }
  end

  def create
  @product = current_user.products.new(params[:product])
  @photo = current_user.photos.new(params[:photo])

    if @product.valid?
      @product.save
      @photo.product_id = @product.id
      @photo.save
      render "show", :notice => "Sale created!"
    else
      render "new", :notice => "Somehting went wrong!"
    end
end

  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @photo = @product.photos
  end

private

  def correct_user
    @product = current_user.products.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @product.nil?
  end    

  def require_login
    unless current_user
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def admin_and_author
    @product = current_user.products.find_by_id(params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @product.nil? || current_user.admin
  end

def admin_user
  redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end

end
```

**application controller**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  helper_method :current_user

private
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
  end

  def admin_and_user
    if current_user.id == 1 || current_user.admin
    else
      redirect_to(root_path)
    end
  end


end
```

**create product page (haml)**

```
%h1 
  create item
= form_for @product,:url => products_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %p
    = f.label :description
    = f.text_field :description
  %p
    = f.fields_for :photos do |fp|
      =fp.file_field :image
      %br
  %p.button
    = f.submit
```

**Rake routes**

```
           products GET    /products(.:format)                   products#index
                    POST   /products(.:format)                   products#create
        new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)               products#new
       edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)          products#edit
            product GET    /products/:id(.:format)               products#show
                    PUT    /products/:id(.:format)               products#update
                    DELETE /products/:id(.:format)               products#destroy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace this line in product page:

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path
```

with

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product)
```

or

```
= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, @product]
```

Comment: Thanks! that was right (I have to wait 5 more mins before I mark it correct)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `render` something in your `edit` method.

Comment: but when you click edit it does link to the edit_product_path

Answer (score 1):

Any `edit` or `show` paths need a reference object. Have a look at my answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17091844/rails-path-helper-doesnt-work). It should help you out.